# Show $f: V \to W$ is Homomorphism iff $f_{ij}: V_i\to W_j$ for $i,j=1,2$ with: $f(v_1+v_2)= (f_{11}(v_1) + f_{21}(v_2)) + (f_{12}(v_1) + f_{22}(v_2))$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $W = W_1 \oplus W_2$ be vector spaces over $K$ and $f: V \to W$ a map.

Show that $f$ is a Homomorphism exactly when there are Homomorphisms $f_{ij}: V_i \to W_j$ for $i,j = 1,2$ with:

$$f(v_1 + v_2) = (f_{11}(v_1) + f_{21}(v_2)) + (f_{12}(v_1) + f_{22}(v_2))$$

for $v_1 \in V_1, v_2 \in V_2$

It seems to me that we must have $v_1 = f_{11}(v_1) + f_{12}(v_1)$ and
$v_2 = f_{21}(v_2) + f_{22}(v_2)$, but how ? I was thinking with some kind of projection that projects a vector onto one of its components, but don't know if that's the idea

Comment: What does it gives you matrix-wise with a adequate basis for the decompositions $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $W = W_1 \oplus W_2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us show this equivalence. First of all one direction is obvious, let us do the second:

We set $\pi_1,\pi_2$ the projections associated to $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ and $p_1,p_2$ the projections associated to $W= W_1 \oplus W_2$.

Then $$f = (p_1 + p_2) \circ f \circ (\pi_1 + \pi_2) = p_1 \circ f \circ \pi_1 + p_1 \circ f \circ \pi_2 + p_2 \circ f \circ \pi_1 + p_2 \circ f \circ \pi_2$$
So you just need to set $f_{ij} = p_j \circ f_{|V_i}$.

What did I meant with my comment? By choosing a basis $(v_1^1, v^1_2,\dots ,v_{n_1}^1 )$ for $V_1$ and a basis $(v_1^2, v^2_2,\dots ,v_{n_2}^2 )$ for $V_2$, we get a basis $(v_1^1, v^1_2,\dots ,v_{n_1}^1,v_1^2, v^2_2,\dots ,v_{n_2}^2 ) $ of $V$. We do the same with the same notations for $W$.

The associated matrix given by both basis is a block matrix:
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
A_{1,1} & A_{2,1}\\
A_{1,2} & A_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}$$
Obviously, $A_{i,j} : \mathbb{K}^{n_i} \to \mathbb{K}^{m_j}$ is the matrix representation of $p_{j} \circ f_{|V_i}$ with basis $(v_1^i, v^i_2,\dots ,v_{n_i}^i)$ and $(w_1^j, w^j_2,\dots ,w_{m_j}^j)$ for $V_i$ and $W_j$, where $p_j$ is the projection associated to the decomposition $W = W_1 \oplus W_2$.